# Get-AzRoleAssignment giving error on using SignInName

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I am trying to assign a user to a virtual machine using Get-AzRoleAssignment command.

I'm not getting any error when I'm using this command:

```
Get-AzRoleAssignment -ResourceGroupName $RGName -ResourceName $RN -ResourceType Microsoft.DesktopVirtualization/applicationGroups -RoleDefinitionName "Desktop Virtualization User".
```

But when I'm using SignInName parameter, like this:

```
Get-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName $SID -ResourceGroupName $RGName -ResourceName $RN -ResourceType Microsoft.DesktopVirtualization/applicationGroups -RoleDefinitionName "Desktop Virtualization User"
```

I'm getting below error:

**`Get-AzRoleAssignment : Cannot find principal using the specified options.`**

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment I got the same error as below:***

[image]

This error may occur if you are providing invalid **`SigninName`**

***To resolve this issue.*** check whether you are provided correct `SignInName` and check that `signinname` is assign to role assignment in resource group like below.

[image]

To use ***`SigninName`*** -> ***Go to active directory -> users -> copy UPN name.*** orelse in your First command in PowerShell   `SigninName` will display you can make use of it.

[image]

***when I run the correct ***`SigninName`*** with same command I  got the result successfully:***

[image]